# Post body parameter in Django Rest Framework Swagger

Tags: post, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I would like to add Swagger to a Django rest framework, but I can't get POST body parameters...

**What I do:**

> serrings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ....
   'rest_framework_swagger',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
       'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
       'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
   ]
}
```

> urls.py

```
schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='My API')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', schema_view),
    ...
]
```

> Views.py

```
class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
        return Response(something)
```

But my swagger always looks like :

[image]

In this case I can't post my body parameter (json) to try it out...
How to fix this

Answer (score 1):

swagger picks the fields name from serializer class, so you have to add the serializer class name in view.

```
class MyView(APIView):
    serializer_class = SerializerclassName
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ...
        return Response(something)
```

Comment: What if I would like to just put the Json data,... (and not specific fields?)

Comment: all json fields map with that serializer class fields, you will get that option for send data in json format.

Comment: what if I use function view, not class view?how to appoint serializer class？

Comment: Swagger not working, when i am integrating with django rest api. Here I am using class based functions having multiple methods django

Comment: You can specify the request body and response from serializers, with this decorator used on the APIView class's REST methods:
```@swagger_auto_schema(responses={200: UserFullNameSerializer}, request_body=UserFullNameSerializer)
```

You can import it with:
```from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `serializer_class`.
For example,

```
class PostSomething(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = rest_framework.serializers.Serializer # here
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    allowed_methods = ('POST',)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use a double quote in data body. With a single quote, an execute button would not be clicked.